# Sum of two ideals, their product, and intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am studying for my algebra qualifying exam in January, and this was one of the questions on a recent exam.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $R$. If  $I+J=R$, show that $IJ=I \cap J$.

Here is my approach, and I just want to know if it is correct or not.

Suppose $I$ and $J$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$ such that $I+J=R$. We wants to show that $IJ=I \cap J$. So, we have the following:

$IJ \subset I \cap J$:

Let $x \in IJ$. Then $x=ab$ for some $a \in I$ and $b \in J$. Moreover, $a+b \in I+J$ and so $a+b \in R$. Since $IJ$ can be shown to be an ideal of $R$, then $x(a+b) \in IJ \implies x \in I$, and, since $R$ is commutative, $(a+b)x \in IJ \implies x \in J$. Hence, $x \in I \cap J$, and so $IJ \subset I \cap J$.

$I \cap J \subset IJ$:

Let $x \in I \cap J$. Then, $x \in I$ and $x \in J$. Hence, $xx \in IJ$, and so $x \in IJ$ since $IJ$ is an ideal. Thus, $I \cap J \subset IJ$.

Hence, we have $IJ=I \cap J$.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that if $x\in IJ$, then $x=ab$ for some $a\in I$, $b\in J$.  You should instead say $x=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and some $a_1,\dots,a_n\in I$, $b_1,\dots,b_n\in J$.

It's also incorrect to say that $xx\in IJ$ implies $x\in IJ$.

Comment: @AllenBell Since you are answering the question, it is more appropriate to post an answer. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: @AllenBell, thank you! I think that is what I thought was not quite correct with my proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I see now why I needed to clarify which step, sorry I am new to the site, so I appreciate your feedback and will keep that in mind.